# first order differential confusion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi I am running into some issues with a question I have. The quesion is a $1^{st}$ODE. Here is the question.

Q: Solve $3xy^2\frac{dy}{dx}+3\frac{y^2}{x}=\frac{1}{x}$

Now I have solved two way, but the solution is given in the book as the sperated method, I would just like to know why integrating factor dose not give the same ans.

method 1.

Using Bernoulli Equation

z=$y^{1-(-2)}$

dz=$3y^2 dy$

I mulitiplyed the given equation by $3y^2$ as shown below

$3y^2[\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{1}{x}]=3y^2\frac{1}{x}]$

give the equation on

$3y^2\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{3y^3}{x}=\frac{3y^2}{x}$

and using the substitution I have a ODE in the following:

Now using separation method and the reason I did this is because I saw they had the same common denominator.

$\int \frac{1}{1-3z}dz=\int \frac{1}{x}$

this the equates too

$\frac{-1}{3}ln|1-3z|=ln|x|+c$

multiplying through and by -1/3 and taking the exponetial of each side

$1-3z=\frac{e^{-3c}}{x^3}$

solving for z

$z=\frac{x^3-e^{-3c}}{3x^3}$

now for using integrating factor

$e^{\int p(x)dx}=e^{\int \frac{3}{x}dx}=e^{3ln|x|}=e^{lnx^3}$

using the formual I get the following:

$zx^3=\int x^3 \times\frac{1}{x}dx+c=\int x^2 dx+c=\frac{1}{3}x^3+c$

solving for z

$z=\frac{x^3+3c}{3x^3}$

Is this correct as my logic goes that the sign of the constant dose not matter they are indeed the fact solutions to this problem. As  I replace $-e^{-3c}=A$ & $3c=B$ the solutions are the same just with different constants. Or have I made a wrong turn somewhere in my thought.

P.s I have mapped the graphs of the two functions where are very similar as long as: $z=\frac{x^3+3c}{3x^3}$ where c<0

Oh I just left z in for simplicity I do no that I have to sub y^3 into the equation to get the general solution.

Comment: The $y$ is squared. The integrating factor method assumes it is not. You would not have made this mistake if you had used the integrating factor method the way it is derived, which is to compute $\mu=e^{\int p}$, multiply both sides by it, and check that you can now write the left side as the derivative of something (when the method is done correctly the "something" is $\mu y$).

Comment: see here http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3*xy(x)%5E2*y'(x)%2B3*y(x)%5E2%2Fx%3D1%2Fx

Answer (score 0):

Having two solutions that differ in the expression of the constant, for instance $a$ vs. $-e^{-3b}$ is harmless as these can anyway achieve the same value (if necessary using complex numbers), which can be determined by specifying initial conditions.

A caveat, anyway: the expression can have different domains (here $\mathbb R$ vs. $\mathbb R^-$), because of mishandling of signs or other peculiarities during the resolution. It is your responsibility to verify every step rigorously or check if the constraints on the constant is legitimate by plugging in the initial DE.